# Вызов первого метода класса значительно дольше вызова последующих. Почему?

Tags: java, proxy, время

Ниже код, где мы работаем с динамическим прокси (заместителем), для замера времени вызова метода.
***Вопрос такой***:
Наш прокси глотает объект `real` класса `RealObject`, и `SympleDynamicProxy.consumer(Interface iface)` вызывает последовательно сначала метод `real.doSomething()`, а потом `real.somethingElse(String arg)` (я имею в виду, что замеряем время мы на вызов конкретно "`REAL.method`", в том плане, что прокси всё равно имеет ссылку на `real`). Самое странное, что хоть метод `doSomething` и проще, выполняется он сильно дольше, объясните пожалуйста почему? Какой то разогрев железа идёт при первом обращении к созданному объекту? Ведь класс уже прогружен, да и объект уже в куче. На что уходит время при первом вызове? Почему последующий вызов сильно быстрее, хоть и `somethingElse` метод "более долгий"?

---

на выходе видим, что
`doSomething()` потратил на себя ~ 265 000 ns
`somethingElse()` ~ 45 000 ns

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import static lib.Printer.*;

interface Interface {
    void doSomething();

    void somethingElse(String arg);
}

class RealObject implements Interface {

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        print("doSomething");
    }

    @Override
    public void somethingElse(String arg) {
        print("Something else: " + arg);
    }

}

class DynamicProxyHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private Object proxied;

    public DynamicProxyHandler(Object proxied) {
        this.proxied = proxied;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("**** proxy: " + proxy.getClass() + ", method: " + method + ", args: " + args);
        if (args != null)
            for (Object arg : args)
                System.out.println("  " + arg);
        Object o;
        long st = System.nanoTime();
        o = method.invoke(proxied, args);
        System.out.println("  spent: " + (System.nanoTime() - st));
        return o;
    }
}

class SimpleDynamicProxy {
    public static void consumer(Interface iface) {
        iface.doSomething();
        iface.somethingElse("bonobo");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RealObject real = new RealObject();
        consumer(real);
        // Замеряем время:
        Interface proxy = (Interface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Interface.class.getClassLoader(),
                new Class[] { Interface.class }, new DynamicProxyHandler(real));
        consumer(proxy);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `doSomething` вызывается дольше, потому что это первый вызов метода с помощью рефлексии. В этот момент происходит загрузка необходимых для этого class-файлов (мб что-то кэшируется) вследствие первого обращения к конструкторам или статическим методам. В этом можно убедиться, вызвав утилиту `jmap` из кода вашей программы до первого вызова `Method.invoke` и после. При этом, не имеет значения, какой именно метод мы будем вызывать. Для примера возьмем `Object.toString`.

В исходном варианте кода мы получаем, что первый метод выполняется более, чем в 2 раза дольше, чем второй. А теперь добавим строчку с лишним invoke:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RealObject real = new RealObject();
    consumer(real); // <-- это не вызывается через reflection

    // добавляем...
    try {
        Object.class.getDeclaredMethod("toString").invoke(new Object());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Замеряем время:
    Interface proxy = (Interface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Interface.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class[] { Interface.class }, new DynamicProxyHandler(real));
    consumer(proxy);
}
```

И время выполнения методов становится примерно одинаковым.

Comment: Не совсем точно, но разобраться с проблемой помогло. Скорее не просто к рефлексии нужно прибегнуть, вызовом чего то из `Object`, а нужно в `consumer()` добавить например `iface.doSomething()` перед первым таким же вызовом, и получится: `doSomething.1 ~ 200 000 ns`, `doSomething.2 ~ 30 000 ns` и наконец ура: `somethingElse ~ 40 000 ns`

Comment: у меня после любого вызова `method.invoke` на второй раз время выполнения становилось в 2 раза меньше. но если вызывать `doSomething` через рефлекшн, то оно становилось совсем близких значений. т.е. большую часть времени экономило именно загрузка классов рефлекшн. по крайней мере, у меня эксперимент показал такие результаты. а также через `jmap` было видно, что в момент первого вызова `invoke` количество загруженных классов изменялось. других объективных отличий прохождения метода `invoke` между первым и последующими разами, я не нашла.